# How would I color values in a scatterplot in ggplot2 IF the variable is defining how it is plotted?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
      Species Country               IUCN_Area IUCN.Estimate Estimate.year
1 Reticulated   Kenya                    Embu             0          2018
2 Reticulated   Kenya Laikipia_Isiolo_Samburu          3043          2018
3 Reticulated   Kenya                Marsabit           625          2018
4 Reticulated   Kenya                    Meru           999          2018
5 Reticulated   Kenya                 Turkana             0          2018
6 Reticulated   Kenya              West Pokot             0          2018
  GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate UpperCI_detect LowerCI_detect
1                         130            277            -17
2                       16414          19919          12910
3                          57            347           -233
4                        4143           6232           2054
5                           0              0              0
6                           0              0              0
```

I want to create a scatterplot which has on the x-axis "IUCN Estimate", and on the y-axis the "GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate". I then want to color the dots by type, i.e. "IUCN" and "GEC". However, how would I color the dots by their type, if the variables are defining the axes? I'm pretty sure there must be a simple code to layer on, but it's been stumping me so far. I've also tried rejigging the dataset but haven't managed to get anywhere. Here's the plot code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=IUCN.Estimate, y=GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate, shape=Species)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)+
  theme_classic()
```

And here is the data:

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Maasai", 
"Reticulated", "Southern"), class = "factor"), Country = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Botswana", "Kenya", "Tanzania"
), class = "factor"), IUCN_Area = structure(c(4L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 
23L, 25L), .Label = c("Burigi-Biharamulo", "Central District", 
"Chobe", "Embu", "Kajiado", "Katavi-Rukwa", "Kilifi", "Kitui", 
"Kwale", "Laikipia_Isiolo_Samburu", "Makueni/ Machakos", "Marsabit", 
"Meru", "Moremi GR", "Narok", "Ngamiland", "No IUCN Estimate", 
"Nxai and Makgadikgadi", "Ruahu-Rungwa-Kisigo", "Selous-Mikumi", 
"Taita Taveta", "Tana River", "Turkana", "Ugalla GR", "West Pokot"
), class = "factor"), IUCN.Estimate = c(0L, 3043L, 625L, 999L, 
0L, 0L), Estimate.year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L), GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate = c(130L, 16414L, 57L, 4143L, 
0L, 0L), UpperCI_detect = c(277L, 19919L, 347L, 6232L, 0L, 0L
), LowerCI_detect = c(-17L, 12910L, -233L, 2054L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A point is always both `IUCN` and `GEC` if these are the axes, isn't it? Your goal doesn't make sense and can therefore not be coded.

Comment: To be honest this is a data query from a colleague. His goal is to explore the relationship between the points, but each point is not both IUCN and GEC, it is one or the other. But you have made me wonder whether I can convince him that a boxplot would be more appropriate for his purposes.

Comment: Ask your colleague to draw the desired plot by hand. If they can't do that, a computer can't either.

Comment: Thanks, I will. It's good to know that I'm not just missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will color the dots by the IUCN_Area:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=IUCN.Estimate, y=GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate, shape=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=IUCN_Area)) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)+
  theme_classic()
```

And the following by IUCN.Estimate.  As IUCN is a numeric value, ggplot default colors by range values.  Where as in above, the factor value colors by discrete values.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=IUCN.Estimate, y=GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate, shape=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=IUCN.Estimate)) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)+
  theme_classic()
```

As OP requested to color by both IUCN and GEC below, this will do this.  How it is interpreted may be another matter.  But any value can be given to the color variable.  Here, I've added the two numbers together and set as.factor().  Presumably in large datasets the sum of the points might identify a group of note.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=IUCN.Estimate, y=GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate, shape=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=as.factor(IUCN.Estimate+GEC_Stratum_Detect_Estimate))) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)+
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thank you Soren- that's really interesting that you can simply combine (factorial) colors in that way! Certainly useful to know.